# Node.js error now occurs after upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I'm building Ubuntu's virtual environment on Windows 10 using VirtualBox and Vagrant.

After updating from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS yesterday, an error occurred when running node.js.

I get an error when I try to launch a web application as follows:

```
$ PORT=8000 npm start

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:57
log.progressEnabled = log.gauge.isEnabled()
                                ^

TypeError: log.gauge.isEnabled is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:57:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:22:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:152:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
```

This error did not occur before the Ubuntu version upgrade.

How can I solve this error?

---

I tried the following, but it did not work well.

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npm install --reset-cache
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:57
log.progressEnabled = log.gauge.isEnabled()
                                ^

TypeError: log.gauge.isEnabled is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:57:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:22:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:152:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing node_modules and run `npm install --reset-cache` hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, it did not work well.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npmlog/issues/48#issuecomment-295635727
Take a look at this!!

Comment: Thank you,Yogesh.I do not know how to use npm, but I solved it by using yarn.